# Newbie to python-- problem on Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python

I worked on using the slope and the distance formula here. But I think indexing is the wrong approach, or is it?

```
class Line():
    def __init__(self,coord1,coord2):
        self.coord1 = coord1
        self.coord2 = coord2

    def distance(self):
        return ((coord2[0]-coord1[0])**2 + (coord2[1]-coord1[1])**2)**0.5

    def slope(self):
        return (coord2[1] - coord1[1])/(coord2[0]-coord1[0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the class specific variables you need to use `self.#varibale name` So your functions should look like this:

```
    def distance(self):
        return ((self.coord2[0]-self.coord1[0])**2 + (self.coord2[1]-self.coord1[1])**2)**0.5

    def slope(self):
        return (self.coord2[1] - self.coord1[1])/(self.coord2[0]-self.coord1[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming coord is a tuple I prefer to unpack them first for readability:

```
def slope(self):
    x1,y1 = self.coord1
    x2,y2 = self.coord2
    return (y2 - y1)/(x2-x1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with indexing. You might find it more readable if you provide more descriptive names for the components. For example,

```
def distance(self):
    c1x = self.coord1[0]
    c1y = self.coord1[1]
    c2x = self.coord2[0]
    c2y = self.coord2[1]

    return ((c2x - c1x)**2 + (c2y - c1y)**2)**0.5
```

which you can make less verbose with tuple unpacking:

```
def distance(self):
    c1x, c1y = self.coord1
    c2x, c2y = self.coord2

    return ((c2x - c1x)**2 + (c2y - c1y)**2)**0.5
```

and even *less* verbose by working on the complex plane:

```
def distance(self):
    return abs(complex(**self.coord2) - complex(**self.coord1))
```

(For `slope`, the complex-number trick involves converting the difference between the two to polar coordinates with `cmath.polar`.)

Comment: what is the use of "complex"?

Comment: It creates a complex number from the coordinate pair, e.g `(3, 0)` becomes `3+0j`. Since complex numbers can be views as points in the complex plane, the distance between two complex numbers is just the magnitude of the vector defined by two points, which is just the absolute value of the difference of two complex numbers. You basically get the squaring and square root for free.

Comment: For example, `abs(complex(3,0) - complex(0,4)) == abs(3 - 4j) == 5.0`.